# Square root in Java

Tags: java

Am I supposed to write in Java like that? If not, how should I write it?

[image]

```
import java.util.*;
public class Soru {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int m,n,c;
        double f=0;
        Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the m value :");
        m=type.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the n value :");
        n=type.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the c value :");
        c=type.nextInt();       
        f=Math.pow(c, m/n);
        System.out.println("Resul:"+f);
    }
}
```

Comment: like other langauges, `m/n` will be an integer. and for `m=1,n=2`, you will get `m/n=0`

Answer (score 6):

Like with other langauges, `m/n` will be an integer, and for `m=1,n=2`, you will get `m/n=0`

Consider making `m` and `n` as `doubles` - or cast them to it in the evaluation, if you want a non integer result.

Example:

```
int m = 1, n = 2, c = 9;
System.out.println(Math.pow(c, m/n));
System.out.println(Math.pow(c, ((double)m)/n));
```

Will yield:

```
1.0
3.0
```

Comment: `Math.pow` takes 2 doubles as arguments, so changing the `type.nextInt()` to `type.nextDouble()` should do it (and obviously changing the declarations of `m` and `n` to doubles instead of ints)

Answer (score 1):

Though your logic is correct and will work perfectly if **m/n is an int** there are cases where it will fail to give the correct result. For example, 
**5^(5/2)** will give the result of **5^2**. So make the following changes:

```
int m,n,c;
double f=0;
Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the m value :");
m=type.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter the n value :");
n=type.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter the c value :");
c=type.nextInt();
f=Math.pow(c, (double)m/n);
System.out.println("Resul:"+f);
```

Full code as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Soru {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m,n,c;
        double f=0;
        Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the m value :");
        m=type.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the n value :");
        n=type.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the c value :");
        c=type.nextInt();
        f=Math.pow(c, (double)m/n);
        System.out.println("Resul:"+f);    
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter the m value :5
Enter the n value :2
Enter the c value :2
Resul:5.65685424949238
```